# What would /ɯ/ most likely be replaced by?

Tags: phonology, vowels, borrowing, conlang, creoles

If a language was borrowing words from another language that has /ɯ/, what would the first language possibly substitute it with?

Borrowing language phonology -
Consonants:
`m n ɲ p b t d c ɟ k g ts dz ʧ ʤ f v s z ʃ ʒ h r~ɾ l j`

Vowels:
`ɑ aː o oː u uː ɛ eː i iː ø øː y yː`

Comment: Well, it probably wouldn’t be /tʃ/, but there’s no way to say, a priori, what vowel it would be. The most obvious candidates would probably be /u/, /i/, /o/, /y/, /ø/, but which one it would end up being is entirely down to the language and its speakers. Different speakers may even use different sounds for it.

Comment: Voting to reopen as I don't think this question is opinion-based -- there must be data out there about the adaptation of loanwords containing [ɯ].

Comment: This is opinion-based because it's not asking for empirical evidence. Try [conlang.se].

Comment: The most common language with [ɯ] is Japanese and, as far as I know, in all the other languages borrowed Japanese words with [ɯ] give [u] of a sort: _samurai, tsunami, sushi_, etc. I'm for reopening the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid no-one has collected comprehensive data yet for sound shifts due to borrowing/naturalizing foreign sounds. As a substitute we have some [diachronic data (link to the Searchable Index Diachronica)](https://chridd.nfshost.com/diachronica/search?q=%c9%af) what sound are possible outcomes from /ɯ/, the outcomes include /u/ and /i/ (the most expected and obvious ones), as well as /ɰa/ (a diphthongisation). Again, data are sparse.